# Autenticacion ldap error javax.naming.AuthenticationException:

Tags: java, authentication, exception, ldap

I have the following code and when I try it gives me this error:

javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903D9, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v2580

And the code is this:

```
public void inicializarConexion() {
    Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://dc2012.cigb.edu.cu:389");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "uid=Yanet Lopez Hurtado,ou=Nuevos usuarios,ou=Usuarios del CIGB,dc=cigb,dc=edu,dc=cu");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "unica123");

    try {
        dc = new InitialDirContext(env);
        setAutenticado(true);
    } catch (NamingException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error Autenticando mediante LDAP, Error causado por : " + ex.toString());
        setAutenticado(false);
    }
}
```

Please if someone can tell me what happens, I've been weeks and trying to find the error

Comment: ldap error 49 is LDAP_INVALID_CREDENTIALS

Comment: Maybe something is wrong with the account itself. Check if the account isn't locked or try resetting the password.